# How to convert epoch to gregorian datetime in haskell

Tags: haskell, time, epoch, gregorian-calendar

Let's say I have an integer representing Epoch time, for example `epoch = 1499055085`, and I want to convert it to `UTCTime` in Haskell. 
How can I do this?

In other languages this is a very trivial task, why is it so difficult in haskell?

Comment: The answer to this question depends _heavily_ on what those seconds are. Are they unix time, which ignores leap seconds? Or are they seconds in UTC, and if so, since what epoch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who says it is difficult?

You can simply use [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert the epoch (an integer) to `POSIXTime`.

Next we can use [**`posixSecondsToUTCTime :: POSIXTime -> UTCTime`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/latest/doc/html/Data-Time-Clock-POSIX.html#v:posixSecondsToUTCTime) to obtain the `UTCTime`, and finally we use the [**`utctDay :: UTCTime -> Day`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/latest/doc/html/Data-Time-Clock.html#v:utctDay) to get the day part of the `UTCTime`.

In case you want a (year,month,day) tuple, we can use the [**`toGregorian :: Day -> (Integer,Int,Int)`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/latest/doc/html/Data-Time-Calendar.html#v:toGregorian) method.

So we can use the following method:

```
import Data.Time.Calendar(toGregorian)
import Data.Time.Clock(utctDay,UTCTime)
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX(posixSecondsToUTCTime)

epochToUTC :: Integral a => a -> UTCTime
epochToUTC = posixSecondsToUTCTime . fromIntegral

epochToGregorian :: Integral a => a -> (Integer,Int,Int)
epochToGregorian = toGregorian . utctDay . epochToUTC
```

And then for instance:

```
Main> epochToGregorian 1234567
(1970,1,15)
Main> epochToGregorian 123456789
(1973,11,29)
Main> epochToGregorian 1234567890
(2009,2,13)
```

Comment: it is difficult because I have to import 3 modules and know exactly what each module contains, which for a newbie like me is tiresome.

Comment: How many other languages do you know of where date conversion operations are just there by default and you don't need to know about them to use them?

Comment: Importing three modules is precisely three lines of code; I can't imagine how that is tiresome. Furthermore, you can have `import Data.Time` to get the first two modules, if you really consider 1 line vs. 2 an improvement. Finally, you don't have to "know" what each module contains - all you must be able to do is read documentation (that very documentation is linked in this answer!).

Comment: I calmed down and found this useful tutorial on this matter: https://two-wrongs.com/haskell-time-library-tutorial

Answer (score 5):

Not a bad question at all, in spite of the down votes. So what would be the equivalent of fairly standard "strptime" and "strftime" here?

You find this rather complicated, and I agree, as I spent a fair amount of time figuring this out (n00b here), so here are some of my findings. It is not simple, because:

1. Handling time is complicated.
2. The Data.Time library focuses on type safety (consistent with Haskell), which also means that there is no automatic type conversion done for you. Therefore, you must be aware of a thing or two on that matter.
3. How to read epoch depends on what exactly it stands for and how it is stored. Thus if there is no implementation of a universal function `epoch -> utc` in the standard library, it is not an omission, it is because it cannot exist.

It's simpler in say python as `datetime` ship with "pretty good defaults" inferred from your environment. The concept of a "good enough default parameter value for most circumstances" is not something that works well with Haskell.

If the epoch value comes from some arbitrary integer, then Willem Van Onsem's `epochToUTC` works. It if is a timestamp from a file (`EpochTime`), we need another function as this is not quite an integer (it looks like an integer, it behaves like an integer, but it is neither `Int` nor `Integer`—that is some very deep water).

As for the `import` statements, you may simplify this to a mere `import Data.Time`, which will grab all we need from this module, with the exception of `posixSecondsToUTCTime`, because... I suppose it is deemed as sort of specialized.

```
import System.Posix.Types(EpochTime)
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX(posixSecondsToUTCTime)

epochToUTC :: EpochTime -> UTCTime
epochToUTC = posixSecondsToUTCTime . realToFrac
```

Example in ghci: (timestamp of current working directory)

```
import System.Posix.Files

fStat <- getFileStatus "."
let someTime = epochToUTC . modificationTime $ fStat
```

And we are good to manipulate this time value. Note that the `EpochTime` is specific to the `System.Posix` module. If it is a timestamp retrieved from say a database or a web page, it could be yet another story (type safety is not free).

Just as this "strptime" operation was not terribly familiar, a similar story goes with a "strftime"-like operation. This would be done with `formatTime`. Example:

```
formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d" someTime

--equivalent
formatTime defaultTimeLocale ( iso8601DateFormat Nothing ) someTime

--whichever dateFmt defined in that TimeLocale
formatTime defaultTimeLocale ( dateFmt defaultTimeLocale ) someTime

--"%a, %_d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"
formatTime defaultTimeLocale rfc822DateFormat someTime
```

If always on `defaultTimeLocale`, then you can elegantly abbreviate to:

```
formatTime' = formatTime defaultTimeLocale
```

Readings:

[A Haskell Time Library Tutorial](https://two-wrongs.com/haskell-time-library-tutorial) (We need more like this!)

[Time - HaskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Time)

Comment: Thank you so much for your informative answer , and I think the downvotes are probably due to noob hostility in Haskell community. And after all this time, your provided link is greatly appreciated

Comment: Glad to help. I don't think it's noob hostility. Haskellers feel very strongly about their language, which is a double edged sword. Ask a question, expect an answer. Ask a question while expressing a strong opinion, expect an answer with... a strong opinion.

Comment: May be you are right. I guess I asked this question at a time of extreme frustration